# WorkManager setProgressAsync - wait until all progress has finished before completing work

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using the `WorkManager` to perform work.  I am observing its intermediate progress using the `setProgressAsync` function.  An example of how this is used can be found on the `WorkManager` documentation below.

https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/observe#update_progress

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.Data
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

class ProgressWorker(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, parameters) {

    companion object {
        const val Progress = "Progress"
        private const val delayDuration = 1L
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val firstUpdate = workDataOf(Progress to 0)
        val lastUpdate = workDataOf(Progress to 100)
        setProgressAsync(firstUpdate)
        setProgressAsync(lastUpdate)
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

This is how I observe the progress events.

```
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    // requestId is the WorkRequest id
    .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(requestId)
    .observe(observer, Observer { workInfo: WorkInfo? ->
            if (workInfo != null) {
                val progress = workInfo.progress
                val value = progress.getInt(Progress, 0)
                // Do something with progress information
            }
    })
```

The issue I am having is that some of my progress events are being skipped/missed.  After reading the documentation more closely, it looks like the reason for this is because my work is in the `SUCCEEDED` state.  Progress events can only be observed when the work is in the `RUNNING` state.

Here is the statement from the documentation that explains this.

> Progress information can only be observed and updated while the
> ListenableWorker is running. Attempts to set progress on a
> ListenableWorker after it has completed its execution are ignored.

What's odd is that I am calling `setProgressAsync` before the work is complete while the work is in the `RUNNING` state.  My guess is that since `setProgressAsync` function is async that maybe it is just being processed after the job is completed and therefore the progress events are missed.

Is there a way to guarantee that all the progress events get processed and that none are missed?

Comment: Try calling `setProgressAsync(...).get()`. This will block execution on the the future resolves. I ran into similar issues using a CoroutineWorker calling `setProgress`.  Exceptions were being thrown because the progress future had not resolved before the worker finished. After resolving other issues with my code those went away and the final progress (triggered shortly before the worker completes) is being received by the observer. I also detect `WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEED` in the activity and update progress as a redundancy.

Comment: You might update your example to set the progress to 0, then wait some period of time before updating the progress again. That would model behavior in a more practical case. My code downloads a chunk of data in between each call to `setProgress`.